# Jetpack Compose Phone Screen Layout Preview

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

I'm new to Jetpack Compose. I created an app and as a preview I get only the views, in my case a text view.

How can I preview a screen and not an individual element?[image]

I want something like that:

[image]

I am using Android Studio 2020.3.1 Canary 8.

Comment: just build a composable function with more elements.

Comment: But I won't see them in a screen preview. I want something like that https://blog.novoda.com/content/images/2016/10/Screen-Shot-2016-10-12-at-12-16-24.png

Comment: Use `@Preview(showSystemUi = true)`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use the annotation `@Preview(showSystemUi = true)`.

More info about the preview annotations [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tooling).